# Unable to get single quotes from Apache camel route XML config to Java method

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel

I am defining an Apache camel route using XML configurations, and I want to call a method while passing parameters with single quotes:

```
<bean ref="cmdExecutor" method="execute('BatchQA.bat',
        './input/CamelCMDFile/QATestScripts/', 'Analytics,&apos;qa.user&apos;')"/>
```

The execute method looks like this:

```
public int execute(String bat, String dir, String arguments, Exchange exchange) {
    String[] args = arguments.split(",");
    result = ProcessUtils.cmdExecute(bat, dir, args);
    .....
```

I have tried using `&apos;, &#39; and &#x27;` to get the required result, but neither have worked. These characters are simply being ignored in the `arguments` object and the rest of the string is received as it is in my java function.

After applying @Screwtape solution, argument I am getting `&apos;qa.user&apos;` and this is not what I am aiming.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can I clarify? Are you saying that arguments is receiving the values "Analytics" and "qa.user" when split? I think the problem may be that the camel XML is interpreting your &apos; and thus they aren't getting to the bean processor as quoted. You could try either using "&amp;apos;" or I would probably try just doubling the single quotes or backslash escaping them, such as 'Analytics,''qa.user''' or 'Analytics,\'qa.user\''. I'm not sure which Camel would prefer in this instance.

Comment: Thanks. the arguments which I am getting are Analytics and qa.user, but I want Analytics and 'qa.user' as the arguments. I have tried using  "&amp;apos;"  but it throws exception and I have added the exception in question using Screwtape alternatives & using 'Analytics,''qa.user''' or 'Analytics,\'qa.user\'' also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what Camel is doing with these single quoted strings, because it seemed just to strip the apostrophes if you quote with apostrophes such that options I expected to cause errors just seemed to work.

However, I have got it to work as you require. You need to reverse the quotation types. XML allows both single and double quotes in attributes, even though eclipse doesn't seem to colourise the single quoted attributes (but this site does).

Hence when I use

```
<camel:bean ref="testBean" method='test("BatchQA.bat",
    "./input/CamelCMDFile/QATestScripts/", "Analytics,&apos;qa.user&apos;")' />
```

my test bean does break out the strings as you wanted:

```
[WARN ]: beans.testBean - Analytics
[WARN ]: beans.testBean - 'qa.user'
```

although I don't know if it would be possible to have a string like this with both single and double quotes. Let's hope you don't need that.

Comment: Thanks Screwtape! its started working , when i replace ' with " and i get 'qa.user'  but the thing is I want both " as well as ' in my arguments , so after replacing i cant get " in my arguments , So could you tell me any other separater like ' and " or there is any other solution.                                                                             
required solution: 'qa.user',"analytics"

Comment: I was worried you might say that... I can't see how to get a single string to have both single quotes and double quotes in it - I can't see what escaping (if any) is used by the Bean processor without looking at the source code. I can't find any documentation to explain how it is tokenising the `method` apart from here: https://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html and that doesn't explain if there is any escaping process for the methods. Perhaps you should define a property and use that instead of a quoted string?

Comment: Thanks Screwtape, Its not working btw.:) Others also feel free to response.